# Harmonic balance Michael Steer derivation?

Tags: circuit-analysis, non-linear

I was going through harmonic balance method and one of the references I used was Microwave and RF design Systems Approach by Michael Steer . In one of the examples provided , he derives the current harmonics for the non-linear subsystem however I couldn't quite follow how he derived it . Could someone please shed some light? The set of currents on the right side are the ones I couldn't understand. Here's the link to the power point presentation https://people.engr.ncsu.edu/mbs/MicrowaveRFDesign/CS_AmpHB/CS_AmpHB.pdf
[image]

Comment: Diagrams are not clearly visible.

Comment: @Chu corrected the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst the objective of the exercise is to apply an iterative method, based on the Jacobian, this particular system can be solved analytically.

Assuming \$\small e(t) = cos (\omega t)\$, the equation to solve for \$\small v(t)\$ is: $$\small \left ( v(t)\right )^2 +2v(t) - cos (\omega t)=0$$

Solving gives:
$$\small v(t) = -1\: \pm\: \sqrt{1+cos(\omega t)} $$

Decomposing \$\small v(t)\$ into Fourier series components (to do this, express \$\small v(t)\$ in double angle form), the DC component; fundamental; and 2nd harmonic voltages are:

$$\small V_0=-0.1$$
$$\small V_1=0.6$$
$$\small V_2=-0.12$$

which compare with:

$$\small V_0=-0.09$$
$$\small V_1=0.58$$
$$\small V_2=-0.09$$

for the iterative solution.

Comment: True , I proceeded by reducing the diode equation through taylor series expansion which gave me a few more extra terms to deal with but in the end I ended up getting nearly the same result. Thank you